# tikzpicture - Include legend when centering

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, center

I notice that when I centre my plot, it only centers on the graph and ignores the legend. This leaves the legend overhanging my margin. Is there any way to include the legend in the centering process? Example code is below. Thanks.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={at={(1,1)},anchor=north west},
xlabel=xlab,
ylabel=ylab]
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
    (1,1)
    (2,1)
    (3,1)
};
\addlegendentry{Legend1}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Which kind of "centering" are you using? Also please extend your code snippet to a [complete example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the co-ordinates of legends `{at={(0.5,1)},anchor=center}`. Change the value as per your requirements. For example:

- Bottom left: `{at={(0,0)},anchor=center}`
- Bottom right: `{at={(1,0)},anchor=center}`
- Top left: `{at={(0,1)},anchor=center}`
- Top right: `{at={(1,1)},anchor=center}`

For your graph: the center position should be: `{at={(0.5,1)},anchor=center}`

Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={at={(0.5,1)},anchor=center},
xlabel=xlab,
ylabel=ylab]
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
    (1,1)
    (2,1)
    (3,1)
};
\addlegendentry{Legend1}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```